# Botframework AdaptiveCard is losing the “actions” node over directline

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm using the botframework C# with directlinejs to build my bot.

Recently I've noticed that my bot stoped working and I just find out that the problem is that the directline/botconnector or something in the middle is losing the "actions" node of my AdaptiveCard over directline. Here is the message that my bot (server) is sending to the client (botconnector and directlinejs).

```
{
  "$type": "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity, Microsoft.Bot.Connector",
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2018-04-19T17:57:14.565727+00:00",
  "serviceUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/",
  "channelId": "directline",
  "from": {
    "$type": "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Connector",
    "id": "Toro@Q7xWzEtd_lk",
    "name": "Toro Assistant"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "$type": "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Connector",
    "id": "CfAgYrLQOuv9fDMPnfINDG"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "$type": "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ChannelAccount, Microsoft.Bot.Connector",
    "id": "anonymous",
    "name": "anonymous"
  },
  "text": "",
  "attachments": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment, Microsoft.Bot.Connector]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment, Microsoft.Bot.Connector",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content": {
          "$type": "AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard, AdaptiveCards",
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "version": "1.0",
          "body": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveElement, AdaptiveCards]], mscorlib",
            "$values": [
              {
                "$type": "AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveTextBlock, AdaptiveCards",
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Não se preocupe, cadastrar um novo número é muito fácil. É só clicar no botão abaixo.\r\n\r\n"
              }
            ]
          },
          "actions": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveAction, AdaptiveCards]], mscorlib",
            "$values": [
              {
                "$type": "AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveOpenUrlAction, AdaptiveCards",
                "type": "imBack",
                "url": "http://toroinvestimentos.com.br/minhaconta/emailecelular/edit?q=phone&token=token",
                "title": "Falar com Assessor"
              },
              {
                "$type": "AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveSubmitAction, AdaptiveCards",
                "type": "imBack",
                "data": "Mudar de assunto",
                "title": "Mudar de assunto",
                "image": "https://toro.azureedge.net/bot/icon_list_default.svg"
              }
            ]
          },
          "style": "ToroCard1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "entities": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Entity, Microsoft.Bot.Connector]], mscorlib",
    "$values": []
  },
  "replyToId": "CfAgYrLQOuv9fDMPnfINDG|0000011"
}
```

And here is the message that the botconnector/directlinejs is delivering to the client:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "id": "CfAgYrLQOuv9fDMPnfINDG|0000012",
  "timestamp": "2018-04-19T17:57:14.9161386Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2018-04-19T17:57:14.6134302+00:00",
  "channelId": "directline",
  "from": {
    "id": "Toro",
    "name": "Toro Assistant"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "CfAgYrLQOuv9fDMPnfINDG"
  },
  "text": "",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
      "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "version": "1.0",
        "body": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Não se preocupe, cadastrar um novo número é muito fácil. É só clicar no botão abaixo.\r\n\r\n"
          }
        ],
        "style": "ToroCard1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "entities": [],
  "replyToId": "CfAgYrLQOuv9fDMPnfINDG|0000011"
}
```

Note that the "Actions" node of my message was croped by something in the middle (botconnector or directlinejs, I don't know).
Could anyone help me ?

I'm using the following version o botframework libs:

Microsoft.Bot.Builder version="3.14.1.1"
Microsoft.Bot.Connector" version="3.14.1.1"

Comment: The same issue is happening after updating the Microsoft.Bot.Builder to version="3.15.0" Microsoft.Bot.Connector" version="3.15.0"

Comment: Could you share the code of your bot application and directlinejs client? it would help reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @FeiHan, I would love to share my application code, unfortunately my company's polices, doesn't allow me to do that. To reproduce the bug simply create a new bot an return and make it post an instance of an AdaptiveCard with an AdaptiveOpenUrlAction assined to it's "Actions" property. You will notice that the AdptiveCard instance will be sent to the client, but the "Actions" property will NOT be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"type": "imBack"` is not a valid **AdaptiveAction** type.

For **AdaptiveOpenUrlAction** it should be `"Action.OpenUrl"` https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/6700649f154cf12da6d02e063325b396026993c6/source/dotnet/Library/AdaptiveCards/AdaptiveOpenUrlAction.cs#L24

For **AdaptiveSubmitAction** it should be `“Action.Submit”` https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/6700649f154cf12da6d02e063325b396026993c6/source/dotnet/Library/AdaptiveCards/AdaptiveSubmitAction.cs#L22

Comment: As suggested, follows the issue created on AdptiveCards github: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/1403

Comment: @Eric I'm trying to send a simple imBack on adaptive card button click in Skype Channel and I just can't find a way. Shouldnt "Action.Submit" with a plain string in the Data property work?

Comment: I don't think Skype supports adaptive card submit actions.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with the following sample code to send AdaptiveCard, and in my directjs client, I can find the `actions` node in message entity. So I suggested for sharing your code in my earlier comment.

***In my bot application:***

```
var replymes = context.MakeMessage();

AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();

// Add text to the card.
card.Body.Add(new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "This is an Adaptive Card",
    Size = TextSize.Large,
    Weight = TextWeight.Bolder
});

// Add buttons to the card.
card.Actions.Add(new OpenUrlAction()
{
    Url = "http://foo.com",
    Title = "Link1"
});

// Create the attachment.
Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Content = card
};
replymes.Attachments.Add(attachment);

Console.WriteLine(card.ToString());
await context.PostAsync(replymes);
```

***In directlinejs client, message entity contains `actions` node:***

[image]

Besides, as Eric Dahlvang mentioned, `"type": "imBack"` is not a valid AdaptiveAction type. If we explicitly specify the type to `"imBack"`, like below:

```
card.Actions.Add(new OpenUrlAction()
{
    Url = "http://foo.com",
    Title = "Link1",
    Type= "imBack"
});
```

***The `actions` node will miss in message entity:***

[image]